Help, finding an angle inside bunches of triangles in a quarter circle
Given that ∠DOC = 15◦ and O is the center of the quarter circle shown below, find
∠BOA.
The diagram is in the link below.
https://i.sstatic.net/vRKhkYo7.png
I only know that COA = 75 degrees; CAO = 85 degrees; and the two triangles inside are similar. I don't know anything else.

What is your attempt for this question?

How to find BOA = snake-hunting ?

Take a tour. Learn more about how to ask questions.

@M.Riyan I might be wrong, but did you write "my attempt" part of the latest edit for OP?

Yeah, I did it. I just tried to be detailed about OP's thought. Nothing's New.

@M.Riyan It seems like you're putting words in OP's mouth. EG How did you get  "I tried applying sine rule to the two similar triangles, but failed to find anything" from "I don't know anything else. "? How do you know that? $\quad$ In addition, "the two triangles inside are similar" does not refer to "OAC and OAB", which are NOT similar. $\quad$ As such, I'm rolling back your edit. In addition, I'm voting to close this question as 3 users who voted to close this question, also voted to open the question, where the main change is M.Riyan's edit, which is not reflective of OP's work.

$\angle DOC = 15^\circ$ implies $\angle COA = 75^\circ$, which then implies $\angle OAC = 180^\circ - 75^\circ - 20^\circ = 85^\circ$.
Notice that $\angle OCA = \angle OBA$ implies that the quadrilateral $OABC$ is a cyclic quadrilateral, which gives $\angle OBC = \angle OAC = 85^\circ$.
The triangle $\triangle OBC$ is an isosceles triangle with $|OB|=|OC|$. The two equal base angles are each equal to $\angle OBC = 85^\circ$, and therefore the apex angle is $\angle COB = 180^\circ - 2\cdot85^\circ = 10^\circ$.
Finally, $\angle DOC = 15^\circ$ and $\angle COB = 10^\circ$ imply that $\angle BOA = 90^\circ - 15^\circ - 10^\circ = \boxed{65^\circ}$.
